# Knitr: Mimicking Private and Public Chunk Variables

Tags: r, scope, knitr, private

## Generalised Approach

In large projects code is organised, depending on the language, in objects, modules, classes, namespaces, etc. The philosophy behind this is segregating variables (and methods) visible only inside these units from variables globally accessible.

## Problem with knitr  Rnw and Rmd

The code in the Rnw and Rmd documents needs to be grouped into blocks denoted *chunks*. This logic encourages to think of your project in terms of separate independent units. However, while we might consider chunks as independent blocks, all chunks variables and functions live in the same global environment. As a consequence, a variable set in a chunk can be overwritten by a subsequent one. This is prone to errors, since a chunk can accidentally destroy, reset or alter a variable intended to be shared by several chunks.

## Possible Solutions

There is no  way akin to setting  "private" and "public" chunk variables. So I am using this strategy.

I create a global `G` environment for variables intended to be shared among chunks:

```
G <- new.env()
```

When a chunk modifies variables `x1, x2, ...` intended to be reused, at the end of the chunk I set them with:

```
G$x1 <- x1
G$x1 <- x2
```

At the beginning of chunks where these variables are needed, I get them with:

```
x1 <- G$x1
x2 <- G$x2
```

And the same goes for methods (functions): `f1, f2, ...`.

### Less clutter

For large documents, to avoid clutter, I might use:

```
local({
  x1 <- G$x1  
  x2 <- G$x2
  ...
  ## If modified x values need to be persistent:
  G$x1 <- x1
  G$x2 <- x2
})
```

These look like hacks and I would like to know if you have a (more) solid solution.